# How to disable textbox from user in asp.net (that text box is attached with a date picker)

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have textbox in my web application (using asp.net), a date picker is attached to this text box (using jquery)..
        I need to disble this text box. User should not enter any text manually, If we pick a date from datepicker, only that date should be shown in the text box.
         I have tried the same thing by changing the textbox property to Readonly=true, This is working fine, It is allowing to select the date from datepicker. but I am not getting that date in my program (txtdate.text )

Comment: try with the property onkeypress="return false;"

Comment: Thank you "Sunil", This is working fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code in your JS file.

```
$('#datepicker').bind('keypress', function (e) {
   return (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57);
});
```

See result here
http://jsfiddle.net/lin/Fa8Xx/1145/

**Update**

Form what you provided in your comment, your dateFormat of datepicker was wrong, try below code

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd,mm,yy', minDate: '0' }).bind('keypress', function (e) {
   return  (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57);
});
```

see result here: http://jsfiddle.net/lin/Fa8Xx/1191/

Comment: $(function () 
{
        $("#txtDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy', minDate: '0' });

        $('#txtDate').bind('keypress', function (e) { return (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57); });
        
    });

This code is not working for me..